# Improving Realm notification performance

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to improve the performance of Realm writes and notifications in my app. When the number of Items grows (100k+) Realm notifications become slow.

#### Example:

```swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

/// Simple Realm object, no relations
class Item: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var someProp: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    override static func indexedProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["name"]
    }

}

class TestCase {
    
    var token: NotificationToken?
    
    /// Queues can be changed, see Scenarios.
    let actionQueue  = DispatchQueue.main
    let observeQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    
    /// Seed 500k items.
    func seed() {
        self.print("SEEDING...")
        
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        let items: [Item] = (0..<500000).map {
            let item = Item()
            item.name = "Item \($0)"
            return item
        }
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(items)
        }
    }
    
    /// Query the database, observe and simulate user actions.
    func run() {
        
        let realm = try! Realm()
        
        self.print("QUERYING...")
        
        let results = realm.objects(Item.self)
            .sorted(by: [ SortDescriptor(keyPath: "name") ])
        
        self.print("OBSERVING...")
        
        self.token = results.observe(on: observeQueue) { changes in
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                self.print("NOTIFICATION", "initial")
                
                // query is ready let user do some actions
                self.simulateUserActions()
                

            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                self.print("NOTIFICATION", "update", deletions.count, insertions.count, modifications.count)
                
            case .error:
                self.print("NOTIFICATION", "error")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    /// Simulate three simple user actions.
    /// Each action changes a prop of a single Item.
    func simulateUserActions() {
        
        actionQueue.async {
            self.print("USER ACTION 1")
            
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                let item = realm.objects(Item.self).first!
                item.someProp = item.someProp + "a"
            }
            
            self.print("USER ACTION 1 done")
        }

        actionQueue.async {
            self.print("USER ACTION 2")
            
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                let item = realm.objects(Item.self).first!
                item.someProp = item.someProp + "b"
            }
            
            self.print("USER ACTION 2 done")
        }
        
        actionQueue.async {
            
            self.print("USER ACTION 3")
            
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                let item = realm.objects(Item.self).first!
                item.someProp = item.someProp + "c"
            }
            
            self.print("USER ACTION 3 done")
        }
        
    }
    
    /// Helper to log things.
    func print(_ args: Any...) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "H:mm:ss.SSSS"
        let time = formatter.string(from: Date())
        
        var threadID: UInt64 = 0
        pthread_threadid_np(nil, &threadID)
        let thread = String(format: "%08X", threadID)
        
        let log = args.map(String.init(describing:)).joined(separator: ", ")
        
        Swift.print(thread, time, log)
    }
    

}
```

(See test app here, including code: [github.com/floorish/RealmPerf/releases/tag/release1](https://github.com/floorish/RealmPerf/releases/tag/release1))

#### Situation

1. The app queries for all Realm items and Realm sorts by name (indexed)
2. The app observes the results for changes
3. The user modifies an item (Realm write)

The write in step 3 is simple and is very fast. But the notification generated by this write that updates the list is very slow (can take a few seconds).

### Scenario 1: write Main + observe Main

If both user actions and notifications are run on the Main queue the application UI blocks.
User Action 2 needs to wait for notification of User Action 1. User Action 3 needs to wait for notification of User Action 2.

```
let actionQueue  = DispatchQueue.main
let observeQueue = DispatchQueue.main

M 12:03:03.0940 QUERYING...
M 12:03:03.0950 OBSERVING...
M 12:03:04.1890 NOTIFICATION, initial
M 12:03:04.1900 USER ACTION 1
M 12:03:04.2020 USER ACTION 1 done
M 12:03:04.2020 USER ACTION 2
M 12:03:05.1850 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1   // UA2 waits for notification
M 12:03:05.1980 USER ACTION 2 done
M 12:03:05.1980 USER ACTION 3
M 12:03:06.1420 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1   // UA3 waits for notification
M 12:03:06.1540 USER ACTION 3 done
M 12:03:07.1290 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1
```

### Scenario 2: write Queue + observe Main

User actions are done on a background queue, so consecutive writes are not blocked by change notifications. Unfortunately while the write itself is really fast, it takes a while before these background queue changes are synced to the Main queue. User needs to wait 2 seconds before change is visible.

```
let actionQueue  = DispatchQueue(label: "background", qos: .userInitiated)
let observeQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    
M 12:5:58.5800 QUERYING...
M 12:5:58.5800 OBSERVING...
M 12:5:59.4780 NOTIFICATION, initial
Q 12:5:59.4780 USER ACTION 1
Q 12:5:59.4890 USER ACTION 1 done
Q 12:5:59.4890 USER ACTION 2
Q 12:5:59.4980 USER ACTION 2 done
Q 12:5:59.4980 USER ACTION 3
Q 12:5:59.5070 USER ACTION 3 done
M 12:6:00.5300 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1
M 12:6:01.5430 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1  // coalesced UA2 and UA3
```

### Scenario 3: write Main + observe Queue

User actions are done on the main queue, while notifications are delivered in the background. Since the write is quick the UI is not blocking. The results change notifications are lagging and are fired after a few seconds. That means that while the underlying Realm data is up-to-date the app doesn't know yet about the changes, so accessing the results is unsafe (list count could have changed which might result in Index Out Of Bounds errors).

```
let actionQueue  = DispatchQueue.main
let observeQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "background", qos: .userInitiated)

M 12:07:55.1780 QUERYING...
M 12:07:55.1790 OBSERVING...
Q 12:07:56.1720 NOTIFICATION, initial
M 12:07:56.1730 USER ACTION 1
M 12:07:56.1860 USER ACTION 1 done
M 12:07:56.1860 USER ACTION 2
M 12:07:56.1970 USER ACTION 2 done
M 12:07:56.1970 USER ACTION 3
M 12:07:56.2080 USER ACTION 3 done
Q 12:07:57.1930 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1
Q 12:07:58.1840 NOTIFICATION, update, 0, 0, 1  // coalesced UA2 and UA3
```

When checking performance in Instruments Realm is using most time in `realm::_impl::ResultsNotifier::run()`.

[image: Realm notification perfomance measurement]

Removing the Realm SortDescriptors on the observed Results **significantly** speeds up the notification delivery.

#### Questions

Why are the notification so slow? The modifications don't require resorting of the results, so I expect the notifications to be quick.

Scenario 3 (writing on the main queue + observing on background queue) allows the user to immediately interact with the changes (which is desired). How can I safely access the Results in this situation, because the Results `count` might have changed so accessing the Results might trigger Index Out Of Bounds.

Comment: We have a dataset of approximately 2GB in size with almost 2 million 'rows' and are not experiencing delays like that. Perhaps there's some additional code causing the issue. Questions asking *Is there any way* are broad and not directly answerable without understanding the use case and the code. I would suggest editing the question and replacing everything from *the Situation* down and with the code that's causing the trouble so we can understand what you're doing. Take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here's the minimal test case: https://github.com/floorish/RealmPerf/releases/tag/release1 I'm not expecting a direct solution to the problem and the scenarios described above are direct observations from the minimal test case, but any pointers are welcome even if that's broad. Are you observing changes on those 2 million rows? And that's instant? Are they sorted? The test case shows 3 second delay when observing 500k items. Removing sort helps, but there is still some delay.

Comment: We are observing a significant number of rows. Are they sorted? Not sure what that means - sorted.. on disk? Sorted Results? Sorted Array? Sorted tableView? Also, don't include links to your code; links can break over time and that would invalidate the question. Include code IN the question so your processes are clear. For example; you ask if they are sorted; are you loading your realm objects into an array and sorting? If so, that's part of the problem. In other words, you may having a coding issue which would mean the scenarios results are based on faulty code.

Comment: I'm asking if your two million rows are observed & sorted by Realm, because I have a hard time believing observing those isn't given significant delays. Sorted means the Realm Results sorted api. No I'm not copying objects. And I know you want a minimal example in code here, but are you really asking for copying hundreds LOC? That IS the minimal example, specific for this problem. Perhaps Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this?

Comment: Added the standard Realm observe code to the question. You can verify the  scenarios by observing the test app in the GitHub repo.

Comment: We are not experiencing any significant delays observing a large number of objects. Often times normalizing followed by denormalizing or refactoring large groupings of data into smaller pieces can often enhance performance so that may be an avenue to explore as well. I would agree that it's just not a good question for SO as we would have to understand and dissect the entire project to determine where the issue is. Some food for thought; if Realm failed miserably for large datasets, it would not make a platform for real-world production so perhaps something else is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your insights, appreciate the help! I've updated the question with a simplified test example. Should be easier to skim through. Scenarios have been updated with output from that specific example. Could you take another look? The Realm object is so simple, denormalising is not possible I guess. Really looks like Realm sorting is the issue here, even though the writes do not change any ordering. Thanks

Comment: Some feedback: I created a small app based on your code and seeded 500,000 Item objects, similar to yours. I did not use any queues `actionQueue.async`. I added an observer to results `let results = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name")`. I have a button that gets the current time, just before the write, writes a new Item to realm, and then in the `case .update` notification outputs the elapsed time `let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(self.startTime)`. Without sort, the result was .18s. With sort it was .95s.

Comment: Our database is unsorted which is one obvious difference. For additional testing, I bumped the seed up to 2M objects and with no sort the notification took .58s. With sort it was 1.67s. Perhaps disk or processor speed comes into play? We're macOS development using SSD drives.I think it goes back to the question; do you really need to observe 500,000 objects? Is there some subset of those that could be observed instead?

Comment: Thanks for confirming, that's exactly the results I'm getting. The updates 'stack', so the next notification is send after `2 * 0.95s` (then it will coalesce multiple notifications, so 2x is the max). If the user does two actions it takes ~2s to see the update. Sounds very inefficient that such a simple write that doesn't change anything on the query itself takes so long to update.

Comment: 500k items is a stretch, but optimising for that gives me some headroom. Some users have ~100k items already, but the Item objects in my app have multiple relations, which slow down the update notifications even more (even if they are empty relations!). The app allows the user to view 'All' items, which works fine with the lazy loading of Realm, just the updates are slow. I could try to use a pre-sorted Realm List, so I don't have to sort in the query itself. Just annoying that I have to do bookkeeping for all different sorts manually in that case.

Comment: Also looks like Realm doesn't use the index on the sorted prop, at least performance doesn't change with or without index. Thats kind of strange, isn't it?

Comment: We are not finding the updates stack - if we continually click the button to insert objects the time to receive the notification is very consistent. Obviously adding thousands of more objects changes that but on a one off basis, it seems to be the same. As a side note, the notification time appears to be dependent on the actual number of objects in the database, not the amount being observed e.g. if the results are limited to 10 or limited to 500,000 the notification response time appears to be the same.

Comment: For each click individually the time is consistent. But if everything runs on the main thread the second click is only fired after the first click is fully handled (including notification, all synchronously). So effectively they're stacked if you click again before the previous notification is received. Interesting that it's dependent on the number of objects in the database, I'll do some tests with that.